# How do I make dynamic ids in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
#item
```

creates a div with id="item"

```
.box#item
```

creates a div with class="box" and id="item"

```
.box#="item "+x
```

creates a div with class="box" and a comment '#="item"+x'

```
.box#
  ="item"+x
```

throws "Illegal element: classes and ids must have values."

How do I get set the id to a variable?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There are two ways:

The long form way (define the id as if it were a regular attribute):

```
.box{:id => "item_#{x}"}
```

produces this (`x` is what ever `x.to_s` evaluates to):

```
<div class="box" id="item_x">
```

The short form way:

```
.box[x]
```

produces the following assuming `x` is an instance of `item`:

```
<div class="box item" id="item_45">
```

See the [HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html) for more information.

Comment: i had to remove the whitespace to make it work: .box{:id => "item_#{x}"}

Comment: how do you concatenate a string and a string-converted variable in the shortcut method? I tried `.box["item" + s]` and variants with no success. Is that shortcut way using square brackets only compatible with variables only?

Comment: @gwho the shortcut method requires x to be an instance of item.
Use the long form string interpolation form to achieve what you're looking for.
.box{:id => "item#{s}"}

Answer (score 11):

You can set the `id` and `class` in HAML the following ways

1. The normal way

   ```haml
   .box.item#item
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="item" class="box item"></div>
   ```
2. If you need to interpolation you can use this format

   ```haml
   .box{id: "item_#{123}", class: "item_#{123}"}
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="item_123" class="box item_123"></div>
   ```
3. This format generates the class and id using the object reference

   ```ruby
   # app/controllers/items_controller.rb 
   @item = Item.find(123)
   ```

   ```haml
   .box[@item]
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="item_123" class="box item"></div>
   ```
4. If you need to prefix something

   ```
   .box[@item, :custom]
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="custom_item_123" class="box custom_item"></div>
   ```
5. If you need a custom class and id generation you need to add the following method to model.

   ```
   class CrazyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
     def haml_object_ref
       "customized_item"
     end
   end
   ```

   And then you will get the customized class

   ```
   .box[@item]
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="customized_item_123" class="box customized_item"></div>
   ```

Refer:

- http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object-reference-
- http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html