# Dynamic class name in HAML

Tags: haml, erb

Is there a better way to convert the following to HAML?

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Best I can do is:

```
  - flash.each do |key, value|
    %div{:class => "flash " + key.to_s}= value
```

But it seems awkward. And `.flash#{ key}= value` doesn't seem to be right?!?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're looking for something every-so-slightly terser, you can do this now in haml:

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
  .flash(class=key)= value
```

Answer (score 14):

A little better:

```
 - flash.each do |key, value|
   .flash{:class => key}= value
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding a variation on the theme:

this erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

could be

```
=flash.each do |key, value|
  .alert{:class => "alert-#{key}"}
    =value
```

similar to [How do I make dynamic ids in Haml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217583/how-do-i-make-dynamic-ids-in-haml)