# Haml: how to generate dynamic id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, string-interpolation

I've got following code in erb which works fine:

```
<div id='flash_<%= flash.keys.first.to_s %>'>
    <%=h    flash[flash.keys.first] %>
</div>
```

I want to convert it into haml:

```
#flash_#{flash.keys.first.to_s}
  =h flash[flash.keys.first]
```

But I receive error:

```
Illegal element: classes and ids must have values.
```

Which is strange as there IS value, 'flash_' part is always present, I get that error even when I do:

```
#flash_#{nil.object_id}
```

Apparently something wrong is with my Ruby interpolation in haml, but I can't get it right. According to documentation http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_  #{} is used to interpolate Ruby and it works in such case:

```
#flash_
  #{flash.keys.first.to_s}
```

but that's not what I want.

To sum up, I want to get the following output:

```
<div id="flash_foo"> blahblah </div>
```

but it can be also:

```
<div id="flash_"></div>
```

How to obtain that with haml?

Comment: Till you are comfortable with HAML use [this](http://html2haml.heroku.com/) converter

Comment: @prem: thanks for that link, it will be very useful for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make dynamic ids in Haml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217583/how-do-i-make-dynamic-ids-in-haml)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
%div{ :id => "flash_#{flash.keys.first}" }    
  =h flash[flash.keys.first]
```