# Mthaml variable inside class

Tags: php, class, variables, haml, mthaml

I'm trying to declare a variable inside a class in [mthaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml), from what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217583/how-do-i-make-dynamic-ids-in-haml) this should do it:

```
$columns = 3
%div{:class => "columns large-#{$columns}"}
```

However this prints:

```
<div class="columns large-">
```

Comment: This syntax should work. Try checking the value of the variable, e.g. by printing it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For me seems that there are several ways to reach your goal:
first you do this :

```
- set columns = 3
```

and then:

```
%div{:class => "columns large-#{columns}"}
```

or

```
%div(class="columns large-#{columns}")
```

or

```
.columns(class="large-#{columns}")
```